# stop an Android service

Tags: android, service

I have searched and found questions similar to the title, but no solution so far. 
I have the following service

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    public MyService() {
    }

    private static final String TAG =
            "ServiceExample";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Service onStartCommand " + startId);

        final int currentId = startId;

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() +
                            10*1000;

                    while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime) {
                        synchronized (this) {
                            try {
                                wait(endTime -
                                        System.currentTimeMillis());
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Log.i(TAG, "Service running " + currentId);
                }
                //stopSelf();
            }
        };

        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.start();
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onBind");
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
        //Log.i(TAG, "Service Destroyed");
    }

}
```

And this is called from my activity that has two buttons: One for starting the service and one for stopping it

```
public class ServiceExampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_service_example);
    }

    public void buttonClick(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }

    public void stopClick(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        stopService(intent);
    }

}
```

However this does not work. The service is not stopped. 
Strangely the onDestroy function is called but after that the runnable is still running. 
How can I stop the service?

=============================================

EDIT: I finally achieved it by the following changes:
In the onDestroy function

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onDestroy");
      //  mHandler.removeCallbacks(r);
        t.interrupt();
        super.onDestroy();
        //Log.i(TAG, "Service Destroyed");
    }
```

the thread t had to be a class member (before it was declared inside onStartCommand) and I modified the runnable as this

```
r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() +
                            10*1000;

                    while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime) {
                        synchronized (this) {
                            try {
                                wait(endTime -
                                        System.currentTimeMillis());
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                return; //HERE to detect if the thread has been interrupted
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Log.i(TAG, "Service running " + currentId);
                }
                stopSelf();//I have to use this otherwise it doesn't stop
            }
        };
```

I wonder why normally I have to use stopSelf but when interrupted it is not necessary. I suppose stopSelf just calls onDestroy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stopping a service just kills the context. The framework does not know about any other Threads you may have started-  its your job to kill them in `onDestroy()`.  Save the Thread when you create it. In `onDestroy()`, interrupt it.  And in your thread's `runnable`, regularly check to see if the Thread is interrupted, and return if so.  Do not call `Thread.stop()`, as it may leave your app in an unsafe state.

Comment: Thanks. I modified the question, with the changes I made according to your advice. It seems to be working now!